# Why are these people in the Purgatory timeline?

Tags: lost

There seems to be a consensus that the alternate timeline (where the flight did not crash) which is shown in Season 6 of *Lost* is some sort of purgatory which the islanders were in before they moved on (to God knows where, but that is not important now).

But Kate, Hugo, Ben and Sawyer never died. So why are they in that timeline?

Comment: What do you mean by "they never die"? I'm assuming they *will* die eventually, no? And this is a future purgatory (or rather one that exists outsides the realm of time)?

Comment: I meant they never died within the timeline of the series.

Comment: Right, but all will die and get there. I'm assuming time is irrelevant there and so is the timing of their deaths.

Comment: Read the transcript of the final scene, your question is explicitly answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But Kate, Hugo, Ben and Sawyer never died. So why are they in that timeline?

Actually that's were you are wrong. The "purgatory" scenes we see are taking place after the death of all main characters. You could say it is sometime in the future, but I doubt that any notion of time exist in that place after all.

How do we know that the events there do not take place right after the death of the smoke monster?

Because the surviving characters talk about their time on the island long after this, where Hurley became Guardian of the island for an extended time, with Ben being his "number two":

> Hurley continued to protect the Island for an unknown period of time, with Ben acting as his adviser. It is unknown how long his tenure as protector of the Island was. In the flash sideways Hurley would later comment that Ben was a good "number two." Ben stated that Hurley also did a great job as the Island's "number one."

(from [Lost Wikia](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Hugo_%22Hurley%22_Reyes))

Answer (score 5):

In the end, Christian says 2 things:

> Everyone dies. Some before you. Some long time after you.

The other is:

> There is no *now*... here.

So it can be concluded that the alternate LA is not present in any moment in the timeline. It is just the place where people go when they die, irrelevantly of when that happens.